# the extracted CNN features using tensorflow are mostly zeros

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, feature-extraction

I trained a CNN model using tensorflow. after that I output and save the features from the fc1 layer, but I find that most of the features are zeros.

My model is as below. I use the h_fc1 layer as the feature. the training and testing seems fine, but I don't understand why the extracted features are mostly zeros, is that normal, or I made some mistakes? I doubt how the input image can be represented by such sparse features. Any suggestion or hints will be appreciated, thanks

```
def get_model(x):
# First convolutional layer - maps one grayscale image to 32 feature maps.
W_conv1 = weight_variable([3, 3, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

# Second convolutional layer -- maps 32 feature maps to 64.
W_conv2 = weight_variable([3, 3, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

# Third convolutional layer -- maps 64 feature maps to 128.
W_conv3 = weight_variable([3, 3, 64, 128])
b_conv3 = bias_variable([128])
h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool2, W_conv3) + b_conv3)
h_pool3 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv3)

# Fourth convolutional layer -- maps 128 feature maps to 256.
W_conv4 = weight_variable([3, 3, 128, 256])
b_conv4 = bias_variable([256])
h_conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool3, W_conv4) + b_conv4)
h_pool4 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv4)


# Fully connected layer 1
# is down to 4x4x256 feature maps -- maps this to 1024 features.
W_fc1 = weight_variable([4 * 4 * 256, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool4, [-1, 4*4*256])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

# Dropout - controls the complexity of the model, prevents co-adaptation of
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

# Map the 1024 features to 10 classes, one for each digit
W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 512])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([512])
#h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool5, [-1, 4*4*512])
h_fc2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)
h_fc2_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc2, keep_prob)

# Map the 1024 features to 10 classes, one for each digit
W_fc3 = weight_variable([512, FLAGS.nClasses])
b_fc3 = bias_variable([FLAGS.nClasses])

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc2_drop, W_fc3) + b_fc3
# here, h_fc1 as the output features.
return y_conv, keep_prob, h_fc1
```

Comment: I find the reason, because of the Relu activation function, which will set any value <0 as zero. so, if we want to extract the features, it seems better to output the value before the activation function, or you may try to use a different activation function.

Comment: The activations of a trained network is a function of many things: the training data, the function that the network implements, the actual image or the set of images used during inference etc. It's not unreasonable to expect many zeros at some layers, especially give the Relu activation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right and that's most likely because of ReLU. However, I would still suggest using the features after the ReLU.

Still, I think it would be a nice experiment to use both and see which one works better. Good luck ;)